# bounce multiple servers using ant

Tags: ant, jboss, exec, restart, build.xml

This is restart target code which is defined in build.xml

---

target name="restart"

propertycopy name="remote.host" from="deploy.${target.env}.host.${remote.id}"

propertycopy name="remote.port" from="deploy.${target.env}.port.${remote.id}"

```
sshexec trust="true"
     host="${remote.host}"
     port="${remote.port}"
     username="${scm.user}"
     keyfile="${scm.user.key}"
     command="sudo /usr/local/bin/bounce_jboss"
```

target

---

server information is defined in build.properties.

The above code is working fine, but the restarting process is very late bcas its stopping-starting server one and later its stopping-starting another server,

Is there a way where i can restart both servers parallely with a time frame of 45 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated the Ant [`Parallel` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html)? You should be able to parallelise the rebooting fairly simply using this.

e.g.

```
<parallel>
    <!-- first server reboot -->
    <ssh ...>
    <!-- second server reboot -->
    <ssh ...>
</parallel>
```

Comment: Yeah i tried even this way 
<parallel>
<sshexec trust="true"
 host="${remote.host}"
 port="${remote.port}"
 username="${scm.user}"
 keyfile="${scm.user.key}"
 command="sudo /usr/local/bin/bounce_jboss" />
 <sleep seconds="45"/>
</parallel>

Comment: <parallel> will parallelise whatever you contain within it. It doesn't run something in a parallel thread whilst doing the rest of the Ant script.

Comment: So (briefly) both ssh's need to run under the <parallel> task

Comment: how to define both ssh's within <parallel>, need to add any condition or loop? Can u give me a example please.

Comment: <parallel>
    <!-- first server reboot -->
    <ssh ...>
    <!-- second server reboot -->
    <ssh ...>
</parallel>
This is not working, each server is restarting two times :-)

Answer (score 0):

The parallel task will work for you.  Another example:

```
<target name="restart" ... >
    <parallel>
        <!-- first server reboot call -->
        <!-- second server reboot call -->
    </parallel>
</target>
```

From command line:

```
>ant restart
```

Don't execute "ant restart" twice.  Only call it once and your servers should only restart once.

Comment: This is how i added:
<target name="_restart">
<propertycopy name="remote.host" from="deploy.${target.env}.host.${remote.id}"/>
<propertycopy name="remote.port" from="deploy.${target.env}.port.${remote.id}"/>
<parallel>
<sshexec trust="true"
host="${remote.host}"
port="${remote.port}"
username="${scm.user}"
keyfile="${scm.user.key}"
command="sudo /usr/local/bin/bounce_jboss" />
<sleep seconds="30"/>
<sshexec trust="true"
host="${remote.host}"
port="${remote.port}"
username="${scm.user}"
keyfile="${scm.user.key}"
command="sudo /usr/local/bin/bounce_jboss" />
</parallel> 
</target>

Comment: Actually build is doing a parallel restarts, But due to some clustering problem i want to restrict my restarts to give gap of 30 to 45 seconds between first server restart and second server restart.